# Upload Video to Firebase Using Swift UI

Tags: firebase, swiftui

Here is my code to pick the video from device and upload it to firebase

```
import SwiftUI
import PhotosUI
import FirebaseStorage

class ShareVideo: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var videoURL: URL?
    
    func selectVideo() {

        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { status in
            switch status {
            case .authorized:
                print("Access granted.")
            case .denied, .restricted:
                print("Access denied.")
            case .notDetermined:
                print("Authorization not determined.")
            @unknown default:
                fatalError("New authorization status is available.")
            }
        }
        
        var configuration = PHPickerConfiguration()
        configuration.filter = .videos
        let picker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: configuration)
        picker.delegate = self
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(picker, animated: true)
    }

    
    func uploadVideo() {
        guard let videoURL = videoURL else {
            return
        }
        let storage = Storage.storage()
        let storageRef = storage.reference()
        let videoRef = storageRef.child("videos/\(UUID().uuidString).mp4")
        let metadata = StorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "video/mp4"

        videoRef.putFile(from: videoURL, metadata: metadata) { metadata, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("->>>>\(videoURL)")
                print("Error uploading video: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                print("Video uploaded successfully.")
            }
        }
    }
}

extension ShareVideo: PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {
    
    func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
        
        picker.dismiss(animated: true)
        guard let result = results.first else {
            return
        }
        result.itemProvider.loadFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.movie.identifier) { url, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error loading video: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else if let url = url {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.videoURL = url
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct ShareVideoView: View {
    @StateObject private var shareVideo = ShareVideo()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button(action: {
                shareVideo.selectVideo()
            }){
                Text("Select Video")
            }
            
            Button("Upload Video") {
                shareVideo.uploadVideo()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ShareVideoView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ShareVideoView()
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error
**Error uploading video: File at URL: file:///Users/hitesh/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B28A566B-E082-4802-87CA-E2044ECCE57C/data/Containers/Data/Application/25CE276A-BD92-4D0C-9FBE-C594E9C05E90/tmp/.com.apple.Foundation.NSItemProvider.8pCkyb/SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mp4 is not reachable. Ensure file URL is not a directory, symbolic link, or invalid url.**

Comment: try using `print("Error uploading video: \(error)")` and see if this gives more info on the error. Also try  to have `let picker = PHPickerViewController ...` in `ShareVideo` but outside the function.

Comment: As You said print("(error)") it gave me following error:-

Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mp4” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/hitesh/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B28A566B-E082-4802-87CA-E2044ECCE57C/data/Containers/Data/Application/1805D3A0-B6EA-4A3A-B9EB-CF6A3D1677A8/tmp/.com.apple.Foundation.NSItemProvider.JzVp7g/SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mp4, NSUnderlyingError=0x6000006d1830 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

And can not call picker Outside function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have somehow managed to achieve it

```
import PhotosUI
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import AVKit
import ImageCaptureCore
import AVFoundation
import FirebaseStorage

struct VideoPicker: View {
    @State private var videoURL: URL?
    @State private var isShowingVideoPicker = false
    
    private func pickVideo() {
        isShowingVideoPicker = true
    }
    
    private func handleVideoPickerResult(_ videoURL: URL) {
        self.videoURL = videoURL
    }
    // register app delegate for Firebase setup
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: pickVideo) {
                Text("Select Video from Gallery")
            }.padding()
            .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingVideoPicker) {
                
                ImagePickerDelegate(sourceType: .photoLibrary, mediaTypes: ["public.movie"], didPickVideo: handleVideoPickerResult)
            }
            
            
            if let videoURL = videoURL {
                
                VideoPlayerView(videoURL: videoURL)
                    .frame(height: 200)
                
            } else {
                Text("Tap the button to select a video")
                    .padding()
            }
            
            Button("Upload Video") {
                if let videoURL = videoURL {
                    upload(file: videoURL) { url in
                        print(url)
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
    
}

extension VideoPicker {
    func upload(file: URL, completion: @escaping ((_ url : URL?) -> ())) {
        let name = "\(UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString)!\(UUID().uuidString).mp4"
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
            
            let storageRef =
                Storage.storage().reference().child("Videos").child(name)
            if let uploadData = data as Data? {
                let metaData = StorageMetadata()
                metaData.contentType = "video/mp4"
                storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: metaData
                                   , completion: { (metadata, error) in
                                    if let error = error {
                                        completion(nil)
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        storageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                                            guard let downloadURL = url else {
                                                completion(nil)
                                                return
                                            }
                                            completion(downloadURL)
                                        }
                                        print("success")
                                    }
                                   })
            }
        }catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
        
    }
}
struct ImagePickerDelegate: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType
    let mediaTypes: [String]
    let didPickVideo: (URL) -> Void
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.sourceType = sourceType
        picker.mediaTypes = mediaTypes
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: Context) {}
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(didPickVideo: didPickVideo)
    }
    
    final class Coordinator: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
        let didPickVideo: (URL) -> Void
        
        init(didPickVideo: @escaping (URL) -> Void) {
            self.didPickVideo = didPickVideo
        }
        
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
            if let videoURL = info[.mediaURL] as? URL {
                didPickVideo(videoURL)
            }
            picker.dismiss(animated: true)
        }
        
        func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
            picker.dismiss(animated: true)
        }
    }
}

struct VideoPlayerView: View {
    var videoURL: URL
    
    var body: some View {
        VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url: videoURL))
            .onAppear {
                // Auto-play the video when the view appears
                let player = AVPlayer.shared()
                player.play()
            }
            .onDisappear {
                // Pause the video when the view disappears
                let player = AVPlayer.shared()
                player.pause()
            }
    }
}

extension AVPlayer {
    static func shared() -> AVPlayer {
        struct Singleton {
            static let instance = AVPlayer()
        }
        return Singleton.instance
    }
}


struct VideoPickerView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Homeview()
    }
}
```